# How to center a drawable in a button?

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I want to put an image(Drawable) into a button. But the opcions are drawableLeft/Bottom/Top/Rigth. I want to put it in center.
Background dont work because it stretched my image.
The image is an drawable into drawable folder.
If it possible the code in xml.
Thanks!

The drawable:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/im_perfil"
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="20dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

"im_perfil" is an ImageAsset,

**I CAN! I use src!**

Comment: Does this mean you don't want text?

Comment: I don´t want text, I want to do a BottomNavigation but this widget take the icon to top. So I use normal buttons that make this function. But I dont know how to put the image center. Sorry my bad English :(

Comment: Then use ImageButton

Comment: But I cant put a drawable with ImageButton. Background stretch the image...

Comment: The button must be the 1/3 wigth of screen.

Comment: I can! I use src. Thank you!

Comment: You don't want to use src? Why?

Comment: I use src. Thanks!

Comment: So, is this both a question AND an answer together? You should keep them separate. Please answer your question and accept it, so the post will be removed from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting drawable in image button using src like this

```
<ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/btn_id"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:background="@null"
 android:src="@drawable/im_perfil" />
```